# Convert integers inside a list into strings and then a date in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

i've just started studying python in college and i have a problem with this exercise:
basically i have to take a list of integers, like for example [10,2,2013,11,2,2014,5,23,2015], turn the necessary elements to form a date into a string, like ['1022013',1122014,5232015] and then put a / between the strings so i have this ['10/2/2013', '11/22/2014','05/23/2015']. It needs to be a function, and the length of the list is assumed to be a multiple of 3. How do i go about doing this? 
I wrote this code to start:

```
def convert(lst):
     ...:     for element in lst:
     ...:      result = str(element)
     ...:      return result
     ...:
```

but from a list [1,2,3] only returns me '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split your list into size 3 chunks you use a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) with a `step` of 3

```
for i in range(0, len(l), 3):
    print(l[i:i+3])
```

And joining the pieces with `/` is as simple as

```
'/'.join([str(x) for x in l[i:i+3]])
```

Throwing it all together into a function:

```
def make_times(l):
    results = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), 3):
        results.append('/'.join([str(x) for x in l[i:i+3]]))
    return results
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Could you explain the use of step tho'? I don't understand how the splitting happens.

Comment: Basically, instead of counting `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, we're by threes `0, 3, 6`.  Then we use list slicing to take `l[i:i+3]`, everything from the `i` index up to (but not including) the `i+3` index. Then on the next iteration of the loop, `i` is equal to the old `i` plus three. So we're taking 3-wide slices from the list, starting every third element.  I recommend playing around a little with list slicing and `range` to get comfortable with them

Answer (score 1):

```
testList = [10,2,2013,11,2,2014,5,23,2015]

def convert(inputList):
    tempList = []
    for i in range (0, len(inputList), 3): #Repeats every 3 elements
        newDate = str(inputList[i])+"/"+str(inputList[i+1])+"/"+str(inputList[i+2]) #Joins everything together
        tempList.append(newDate)
    return tempList

print(convert(testList))
```

Saswata sux

Answer (score 0):

Use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to extract the date and and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format it:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [10,2,2013,11,2,2014,5,23,2015]
for i in range(0, len(dates), 3):
    d = datetime(dates[i+2], dates[i], dates[i+1])
    print(d.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
10/02/13
11/02/14
05/23/15
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
def convert(lst):
    string = ''
    new_lst = []
    for x in lst:
        if len(str(x)) < 4:
            string += str(x)+'/'
        else:
            string += str(x)
            new_lst.append(string)
            string = ''
    return(new_lst)

lst = [10,2,2013,11,2,2014,5,23,2015]

lst = convert(lst)

print(lst)

#output
['10/2/2013', '11/2/2014', '5/23/2015']
```

So create a placeholder string and a new list. Then loop through each element in your list. If the element is not a year, then add it to the string with a '/'. If it is a year, add the string to the new list and clear the string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it returns an empty list.

Comment: Does your input list look like mine?

Comment: Nevermind it works now. I forgot to place return at the right indentation. Sorry.